# Can I get an example of how to cancel a MobX flow?

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

Mobx official documentation states that you can call cancel on the returned promise from a flow. https://mobx.js.org/best/actions.html There are just no examples of how to do it.

The context:
Call async action within componentDidMount, we need to cancel this action within componentWillUnmount. Want to also setState saying the ui can render after the promise is resolved.

```
      componentDidMount() {
        this._fetchRawEguide = this.props.combinedEguide.fetchRawEguide(null, true)
        .then(() => {
          this._fetchRawEguide = null;
          this.setState({   
            loaded: true
          });
        })
      }
      componentWillUnmount() {
        if (this._fetchRawEguide) {
          this._fetchRawEguide.cancel();
        }
      }
```

The Mobx action looks something like this

```
 @action
   fetchRawEguide = flow(function*(date, redirectOnError = false) {
     try {
       const res = yield request(...);
```

Running into the issue where it says .cancel() doesn't exist when it tries to call it.

I've tried to use when() with regular await / async, it didn't seem to work. If someone has an example for await / async that would be great.

Comment: I was thinking the _exact_ same thing as I was reading that, so thank you for posting this question, and then answering it!

Answer (score 2):

This seemed to work

```
this._fetchRawEguide = this.props.combinedEguide.fetchRawEguide(null, true);
    this._fetchRawEguide.then(() => {
      this._fetchRawEguide = null;
      this.setState({   
        loaded: true
      });
    });
```

I think applying .then to the promise returned by flow may be casting it and removing the .cancel function

Comment: But flow is supposed to be used with `async` functions that use `await` instead of `then()` and `catch()`, right?